# Что означает запись/оператор "::" в строке вида "Prawn::Table"? (scope resolution operator)

Tags: ruby

Что означает запись/оператор "**::**" в строке вида "Prawn::Table"?
(**scope resolution operator**)

Comment: `require Prawn::Table` упадёт. Вы имели в виду `require 'prawn'; Prawn::Table`?

Comment: я пишу require 'prawn' require 'prawn/table'

Comment: В вопросе у вас несколько другое, подредактируйте, приведите в порядок.

Comment: В данном случае это обращение с классу Table модуля Prawn. Двоеточие используется для обращения к вложенным объектам.

Comment: в данном случае ответ, думаю, получен - ключевое слово "подмодули". По коду уже начало что-то получаться

Comment: Я всё забываю сказать: поправьте вопрос в соответствии с вашим комментарием, потому что сейчас он фактически неверен.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Это т. н. "scope resolution operator", оператор для указания области видимости идентификатора

В вашем случае это просто получение класса `Table`, определённого внутри модуля `Prawn`. Хотя они оба могли бы запросто быть хоть классами, хоть модулями, на поведение оператора это бы не повлияло.

Он похож на `.`, точку, которая используется в Ruby для вызова *методов*. Но с помощью точки *нельзя* получить **вложенные константы**, будь то вложенные модули, классы, или просто какие-то значения (Ruby, в общем-то, до лампочки, модули и классы это тоже значения):

```
module Foo
  BAR = :bar   # константа

  class Baz    # класс-в-модуле
  end

  def self.qux # метод класса
    :qux
  end
end

Foo.BAR  # !> undefined method `Baz' for Foo:Class
Foo::BAR # => :bar
Foo.Baz  # !> undefined method `Baz' for Foo:Class
Foo::Baz # => Foo::Baz
```

Однако оба можно использовать для вызова методов самого класса:

```
Foo.qux  # => :qux
Foo::qux # => :qux
```

...и точка в первую очередь ищет именно методы:

```
class Wut
  def self.Wat # НЕ ДЕЛАЙТЕ ТАК. Методы принято именовать в snake_case, НЕ с большой буквы
    :Wat
  end
  class Wat
  end
end

Wut::Wat # => Wut::Wat
Wut.Wat  # => :Wat
```

...да и методов отдельных объектов тоже, в теории (но не надо так делать):

```
class Hi
  def hi
    :hi
  end
end
Hi.new::hi # => :hi
```

Есть ещё особый случай использования `::` "у ничего", чтобы указать "абсолютный путь" до класса, игнорируя одноимённые вещи в ближайших областях видимости:

```
class Ambi; end

class Huge
  class Ambi; end

  puts Ambi   # |> Huge::Ambi
  puts ::Ambi # |> Ambi
end
```

[Ruby community style guide](https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#double-colons) рекомендует пользоваться `::` **только** для получения значений констант, но не для вызова методов. Исключением являются вызовы конструкторов вида `Nokogiri::HTML()`, хотя по-хорошему это обычные методы.

Comment: Загрузили, суть, мне вроде понятна, спасибо .. а примеры сложноваты сразу для меня

Comment: @yuriy ну, я постарался полностью покрыть все случаи использования `::`. Пишу не только для вас, поэтому тут больше, чем нужно именно вам, но вам это всё равно может быть интересно, т. к. раскрывает устройство языка :)